# XAML GettingFocus ArgumentException

Tags: c#

We are trying to redirect focus from an ancestor control to a child using GettingFocus but we are seeing ArgumentExceptions getting thrown on some cases.

The cases I've noticed so far:

1. NewFocusedElement has ActualHeight or ActualWidth of 0
2. NewFocusedElement can't get focus

Is there anyway to guard args.NewFocusedElement = element; ?

We are catching exceptions as a temporary solution.

Here is the code:

```
private void OnGettingFocus(UIElement sender, GettingFocusEventArgs args)
        {
            if ((args.Direction == FocusNavigationDirection.Up || args.Direction == FocusNavigationDirection.Down)
                && (sender == this) && (DefaultFocusButton != null))
                // Add extra guard here so that the try / catch is no longer needed
            {
                try
                {
                    args.NewFocusedElement = DefaultFocusButton;
                }
                catch (ArgumentException e)
                {
                    // This focus redirect causes an exception when the element can't receive focus
                }
            }
        }
```